# Read string of numbers from text file and add them together

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have a .txt called output.txt this is the contents of that file

[image: Image of notepad document]

  I want to read the last numbers from each (4th position along)

 and add them all together to get a total. Mainly I want to know how to get the text into some usable variables.

```
import java.io .*;
import java.util.*;

public class PrintTotalPointsHeld
{

    private int count;
    private String id;
    private File inFile;
    private Scanner input;
    private String name;
    private File outFile;
    private PrintWriter output;
    private int total;

 public PrintTotalPointsHeld (String name, String id, String inFilename, String outFilename) throws Exception, IOException
    {
}

   public void processFiles() throws Exception, IOException
{
        // Stores every word as a variable so we can do our calculations later
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile))) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String points = sb.toString();

        }


        output.println("There are " + count + " accounts that together hold " + total + " points. ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have added my code above, I tried messing around with bufferedreader and string builders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Steps the algorithm (code) follows:

1) `Open` the `file` which contains what you want to read (using `BufferedReader`)

2) `Initialise` the `counter` which will store the `sum` (I use `long` because your `sum` can get `extremely big` and an `integer` may not be able to `hold such big numbers`)

3) `Read line by line the file` (getting the next line using `String line = myReader.readLine();`, making sure there is a next line using `while(line != null){` `splitting` each line using `space` as delimiter, keeping the `4th` element of each array (`parts[3]` since arrays start from `0`) which contains the `number you want to add`, and `adding` this number to the `previous sum`

4) `Print` the `number of accounts (i.e. number of lines)` and the `sum` when there are `no lines left to read in the file`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
class myRead{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        long cnt = 0;
        long numberOfLines = 0;
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt")); 
        String line = myReader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                numberOfLines++;
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                cnt = cnt + Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
                line = myReader.readLine();
            } 
        System.out.println("There are " + numberOfLines + " accounts that together hold " + cnt + " points.");
}
}
```

OUTPUT : `There are 3 accounts that together hold 2558543 points.`

Comment: Awesome, had a little mess around and got this working with mine, good explanation too and I understand the algorithm better now. Thank you! And all the other answers too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that the numbers you want to add up are always going to be at the 4th position; use split() method from String class:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
String process = br.readLine();
int total = 0;
while(process != null){
     String[] columns = process.split(" "); //This array will contain all columns from a single row starting index 0
     total = total + Integer.parseInt(columns[3]);
     process = br.readLine();
}
```

Once you calculate the total, only then write the last line to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Using java 8 the following method will read the file, filter out and only work on the line which match "String String Number Number", then sum the final number column

```
public Optional<Long> sumFinalColumnOfFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
    return Files.lines(path)
            .filter(s -> s.matches("^\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\d+\\s\\d+$"))
            .map(s -> Long.valueOf(s.split(" ")[3]))
            .reduce((p, c) -> p + c);
}
```

`.filter(s -> s.matches("^\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\d+\\s\\d+$"))` means that only line which start with a word, then have a space, then a number, then a number, then end of line will be acted on

`.map(s -> Long.valueOf(s.split(" ")[3]))` will split any lines which it receives from the filter on " ", then get the Long value of the final string

`.reduce((p, c) -> p + c)` will sum each number that it receives from the map

Answer (score 0):

Just split the line and grab the fourth element with an appropriate index:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader(new File("test.txt"));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file); 
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line.split(" ")[3]);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is an incredibly vague question, so this is an incredibly vague response.  Use a "for" loop to iterate over the .txt file line by line and store into an array